# Soap web services error when hosting under virtual dir beneath REST services

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, iis

I tried to find some solution on my own, but I failed. I have WCF web service hosted under virtual directory in IIS

```
http://host/soap/myservice.svc
```

Soap services are placed under REST services

```
http://host - REST services address
```

When I am trying to execute methods from the WCF service I get this error (on server side):

> *Failed to lookup a channel to receive an incoming message. Either the endpoint or the SOAP action was not found.*

When I host the WCF service on the same IIS, but as an standalone application

```
http://host:81
```

everything works fine. But I need them to be under those REST services.

Here is client `web.config` generated by svcutil:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IMyService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
            openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
            bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
            allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
              enabled="false" />
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://host/soapservices/MyService.svc"
          binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IMyService"
          contract="IMyService" name="WSHttpBinding_IMyService">
        <identity>
          <servicePrincipalName value="host/host" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Here is `web.config` of soap service:

```
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MyServiceName">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://host/SOAPServices/MyService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IMyService">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```